# Grouped correlation with dplyr (works only on console)

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, dplyr

I'm trying to use `dplyr` to calculate grouped correlations, but something is clearly wrong since the code below **works only in the console**:

```
require(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
xx = data.frame(group = rep(1:4, 100), a = rnorm(400) , b = rnorm(400))
gp = group_by(xx, group)
summarize(gp, cor(a, b))

  group   cor(a, b)
1     1 -0.02073084
2     2  0.12803353
3     3  0.06236264
4     4 -0.06181904
```

If i use the same code in RStudio, i get:

```
   cor(a, b)
1 0.02739193
```

What's happening?

Comment: I can't replicate this. Can you expand on what you mean by the distinction between "in the console" versus "in RStudio"? As a precaution, I would try again both ways in a fresh session.

Comment: @beginneR Thanks, it works. Can you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you experience is related to having both `plyr` and `dplyr` loaded at the same time. Since both packages have `summarize` functions, there can be conflicts if you don't specify explicitly which package you want to use. For the example data, this means:

```
require(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
xx = data.frame(group = rep(1:4, 100), a = rnorm(400) , b = rnorm(400))
```

Using `dplyr` as intended:

```
gp = group_by(xx, group)
dplyr::summarize(gp, cor(a, b))
#Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
#
#  group   cor(a, b)
#1     1 -0.02073084
#2     2  0.12803353
#3     3  0.06236264
#4     4 -0.06181904
```

Or using `plyr`

```
gp = group_by(xx, group)
plyr::summarize(gp, cor(a, b))
#   cor(a, b)
#1 0.02739193
```

So either avoid loading both packages or specify the package by using package::function.

Comment: How would you produce a correlation matrix for each group, so if

    set.seed(123)
    xx = data.frame(group = rep(1:4, 100), a = rnorm(400) , b = rnorm(400),     
    c=rnorm(400)

Comment: @spindoctor, better to ask that in a separate question